# Get location from sun's position and time?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I once heard it was possible to obtain your position from the suns azimuth and elevation and the current time. also, the time from the your and the suns position. I am currently in upper high and don't know of any way to do this using what i already know. So it it possible, if so how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the exact time and date, you can find the **sub-solar point**, the spot on the earth where the sun is directly overhead.

If **you** see the sun directly over head, then your location is the sub-solar point.

More likely, you see the sun some distance from the zenith.  This means that you are on a circle (not a great circle) with the sub-solar point as the center.  The farther you see the sun is from the zenith, the larger the circle. Everyone on that circle sees the sun at the same elevation, but in a different direction.  If you know the direction of the sun, you know which of those people you are...